# Vim mapping doesn't work on newly opened files

Tags: vim

I have a fresh vimrc with the following lines:

```
let mapleader = " "
nnoremap <leader>ft <C-w>v :Ex<CR>
```

If I open a file that exists on disk already and use the command `<leader>ft` the desired action will happen and a new window with netrw pops up.

However if I create a new file with vim on the command line i.e. `vim mynewfile.txt` and use the mapping, a new window is created by is fails to register the second part of the mapping.

Does anyone know if I need to change the mapping somehow to get this to work on new files or whether this is feature/bug in vim?

Comment: Remove the whitespace between `<C-w>v` and `:Ex<CR>`.

Comment: Or better is simply `:Vex<CR>`

Comment: @weirdsmiley, that worked, thank you. Any idea why that makes a difference for newly opened vs already saved files?

Comment: That's because the cursor is already on the last char and "space" fails to move it to the right.